# Servlet Mapping like "/example/one/"

Tags: java, servlets, mapping

I created Servlet class and configured web.xml as

```
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>ExampleServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>ExampleServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.example.ExampleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ExampleServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/example/one</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I check the url "http://localhost:8080/example/one" I get 404 not found. However when I use only /example, it does work. How can I use a mapping like "/example/one".

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8080/example/one/`, i.e. with a trailing slash.

Comment: If trailing slash doesn't work for you, try changing the url-pattern to example/*

Comment: @Sampada But then `/example/one`, `/example/two`, `/example/anything` would point to the same servlet.

Comment: then use /example/one/* . Check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html) for more details.

Comment: It does not work both. I am still getting 404.

Comment: It works now. I forgot to append Application name to url while browsing.